# Why are string tables split into sections in an .rc file?

Tags: windows, winapi

In an .rc file strings are grouped by sections of at most 16 strings.

So in a typical .rc file we usually have something like this:

```
...
STRINGTABLE  // section 1
BEGIN
    IDS_SOMEID_1    "Some text 1"
    IDS_SOMEID_2    "Some text 1"
    IDS_SOMEID_3    "Some text 3"
END

STRINGTABLE  // section 2
BEGIN
    IDS_SOMEID_4    "Some text 4"
    IDS_SOMEID_5    "Some text 5"
    IDS_SOMEID_6    "Some text 6"
END
...
```

and the IDs of the strings in one section only differ by the least 4 bits.

I wonder why these sections need to be specified explicitely in the .rc file. The resource compiler could take care of this entirely so we could have one single stringtable per .rc file section like this:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_SOMEID_1    "Some text 1"
    IDS_SOMEID_2    "Some text 1"
    IDS_SOMEID_3    "Some text 3"
    IDS_SOMEID_4    "Some text 4"
    IDS_SOMEID_5    "Some text 5"
    IDS_SOMEID_6    "Some text 6"
END
```

Does anyone have a rational explanation?

I found some (insufficient) explanations here:

- [STRINGTABLE resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050(v=vs.85).aspx)
- MS knowledge base [Q196774](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=83996) (link doesn't work anymore)

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to already do the grouping in the .rc file as I have manually created big string tables in .rc file without problems which means that the resource compiler actually *will* take care of this. Still I don't have an answer why the Visual Studio resource editor does it like this.

Comment: Probably historic. Windows 3.1 era tools probably required a strict correspondence between RC sections and generated resources.

Comment: @ChrisBecke makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the profound reason this was invented in the first place. Maybe a question of allocation size. Keep in mind RC files where invented in the early time of Windows.

But the [documentation of STRINGTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/stringtable-resource) says:

> RC allocates 16 strings per section and uses the identifier value to determine which section is to contain the string. Strings whose identifiers differ only in the bottom 4 bits are placed in the same section.

Raymond Chen names it "bundles" of strings: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040130-00/?p=40813

A `STRINGTABLE` might have less than 16 strings, it can also have gaps. But it must be the ids between XXX0 and XXXf. And about splitting, it's no! Strings of the same bundle can't be separated between multiple STRINGTABLE, or in different languages.

Comment: The referenced ["future" entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040202-00/?p=40783) is more insightful: It explains that resources were loaded on demand and how complex a task that was. Bundling strings would amortize the costs of bookkeeping and hitting the (floppy) disk. If you were populating a menu, for example, from string resources, a developer could arrange to reduce that hit by up to 16-fold.